# What do the claws around my characters symbol mean?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

[image]

Notice the small claws around my character symbol. I've been wondering for quite a while what those mean, after all, I've only seen them around myself and not in every game I play.

A while ago, I've read about a killer perk which grants him bonusses when a single survivor is alive. Are those related? If not, what else do they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are the target of the killers obsession, caused by [Save The Best For Last, Dying light, or play with your food](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Shape#Unique_perks).
These new killer perks give the killer special bonuses for interacting with you, though the way he interacts with you varies by perk

Comment: Ah, I knew there was a relation to perks.^^ Tyvm for the answer.